# How do I finish the main quest after breaking the Diplomatic Immunity (Thalmor Embassy party) quest with a mod?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I recently downloaded a mod that needs you to go into the Thalmor Embassy: [Become High King of Skyrim](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/41087/).

I went into the Thalmor Embassy before you did in the main quest, and now everyone I need to talk to — Maven Black Briar, Jarl Elisif, Delphine, and General Tullius — are all acting as though they are in the party, so I can't interact with them to complete quests. Is there any way I can finish the main quest or a command I can use to complete the party quest (Diplomatic Immunity)? I do not want to skip back to any saves as I have accomplished a lot.

Comment: What mod did you download / apply, and what if you turn the mod off?

Comment: Please provide the mod you are using. I have a feeling that there was some sort of disclaimer related to the mod about doing the quest prior to the Thalmor Embassy main quest...

Comment: I'd like to know the mod as well. Likely what happens is the game assumes you're at the point in time where the party quest begins, however none of the NPCs are at the party despite their dialog changing to assume they are.

Comment: It was Become High King of Skyrim, you start a war with the Thalmor by going to their embassy and killing them, link to the mod: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/41087/?